# Multiple Form Sliders on One Page (JS Variable Scope)

Tags: javascript, forms, rangeslider

I understand the gist of the problem here but am not sure how to tackle it. 
I have multiple form sliders on one page, and they will add up to a final calculation (showing the user some sort of savings). In the function `finalCalc` there would be no way for it to know what val1, val2, and val3 are because they are out of the scope of the function.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function slider1Change(val){
document.getElementById('slider1Status').innerHTML = val;
}

function slider2Change(val2){
document.getElementById('slider2Status').innerHTML = val2;
}

function slider3Change(val3){
document.getElementById('slider3Status').innerHTML = val3;
}

function finalCalc(val4){
document.getElementById('finalCalc').innerHTML = val1 + val2 + val3;
}
</script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Sales:</label>   <span id="slider1Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider1Change(this.value)">
  </div>


   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Transactions:</label>  <span id="slider2Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider2Change(this.value)">
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Returns:</label>  <span id="slider3Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider3Change(this.value)">
  </div>
</form>

<h2>You could be saving $<span id="finalCalc">50</span> per month by switching to CompanyX</h2>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Change of every slider call the `finalCalc();` and get the values of `slider1Status`, `slider2Status`, `slider3Status`

```js
function slider1Change(val){
document.getElementById('slider1Status').innerHTML = val;
finalCalc();
}

function slider2Change(val2){
document.getElementById('slider2Status').innerHTML = val2;
finalCalc();
}

function slider3Change(val3){
document.getElementById('slider3Status').innerHTML = val3;
finalCalc();
}

function finalCalc(){
var val1=parseInt(document.getElementById('slider1Status').innerHTML,10);
var val2=parseInt( document.getElementById('slider2Status').innerHTML,10); 
var val3=parseInt(document.getElementById('slider3Status').innerHTML,10);
document.getElementById('finalCalc').innerHTML = (val1+val2+val3);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Sales:</label>   <span id="slider1Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider1Change(this.value)">
  </div>


   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Transactions:</label>  <span id="slider2Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider2Change(this.value)">
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Returns:</label>  <span id="slider3Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider3Change(this.value)">
  </div>
</form>

<h2>You could be saving $<span id="finalCalc">50</span> per month by switching to CompanyX</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope problems aside, you're using a variable `val1` in `finalCalc` but you never used it, the original `slider1Change` function uses variable called `val` not `val1`

Set the variables in global scope and update them on each function:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

var val1, val2, val3;

function slider1Change(valArg){
val1 = valArg;
document.getElementById('slider1Status').innerHTML = val1;
}

function slider2Change(valArg){
val2 = valArg;
document.getElementById('slider2Status').innerHTML = val2;
}

function slider3Change(valArg){
val3 = valArg;
document.getElementById('slider3Status').innerHTML = val3;
}

function finalCalc(val4){
document.getElementById('finalCalc').innerHTML = val1 + val2 + val3;
}
</script>

<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Sales:</label>   <span id="slider1Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider1Change(this.value)">
  </div>


   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Transactions:</label>  <span id="slider2Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider2Change(this.value)">
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formControlRange">Number of Returns:</label>  <span id="slider3Status">50</span>
    <input type="range" class="form-control-range" onInput="slider3Change(this.value)">
  </div>
</form>

<h2>You could be saving $<span id="finalCalc">50</span> per month by switching to CompanyX</h2>
```

Comment: I also had trouble getting this one to print the final calculation